# How to make DropdownButtonFormField support multiple line text?

Tags: flutter, dart

A have a `DropdownButtonFormField` which show long text as one of the item. The long text able to show in multiple line on dropdown.

[image: drop down]

However after it is selected, only 1 line of text is shown. The second line become hidden.
[image: selected]

```
String _selectedState = '';
List<String> _stateList = ['a very very long long long long long text'];

                DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                  isExpanded: true,
                  value: _selectedState,
                  onChanged: (state) {
                   
                  },                     
                  items: _stateList
                      .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: value,
                      child: Text(value),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add `overflow: TextOverflow.visible` to your code as follow:

```
 items: _stateList
        .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value,
                       overflow: TextOverflow.visible
                       ),
            );
  }).toList(),
```

Comment: If it's not working so also add the " isExpanded: true," in DropdownButton

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is not the default behavior, but if you want `TextOverflow.ellipsis` on the selected item and still want to show the complete text when the dropdown is open, you can use the `selectedItemBuilder`:

```
 items: _stateList
        .map((value) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value),
            ))
            .toList(),
 selectedItemBuilder: (context) => _stateList
        .map((value) => Text(value, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis))
        .toList(),
```

And since flutters `TextOverflow.ellipsis` is [weird](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18761), because it always cuts off complete words you might want to switch to `TextOverflow.fade` with a forced single line:

```
selectedItemBuilder: (context) => _stateList
        .map((value) => Text(
          value,
          maxLines: 1,
          overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
          softWrap: false,
         ))
        .toList(),
```